# Failure using references variables in classes

Tags: class, pointer

**Theoretical Q**

I'm having some trouble when using a referenced variable in a class.

`Class A` have an `int a=0`. `Class B` has an instance of `Class A`, and referencing `int &a=A.a`, and in the same manner `Class C` has an instance of `Class B` and `int &a=B.a`. Code crashed when trying to update `a` variable when using C instance.

**Relvant Example**

I'm creating a library for TFT+Touch 2.4 screen, to handle buttons more easily.

Libraries `XPT2046_Touchscreen` and `Adafruit_ILI9341` are included here, but initiated in main `.ino` file for easier handling in `loop` and more control in main code.

**1) `MessageTFT`**

A "basic" class was created, called `MessageTFT`. This class creates the graphics, and stores its geometrical properties and color as shown below.

**2) `ButtonTFT`**

`ButtonTFT` based on `MessageTFT` adding touch capabilities to it. Its geometrical and color parameters are referenced to `MessageTFT`. When creating a `button` instance, user defines its properties but, actually it is referenced to `MessageTFT`.

`ButtonTFT` and `MessagesTFT` works as expected. For example a button is defined in `.ino`:

```
ButtonTFT butt;
```

and defined in `void setup()`:

```
  butt.a = 200;
  butt.b = 60;
  butt.xc = tft.width() / 2;
  butt.yc = tft.height() - butt.b / 2;
  butt.txt_size = 1;
  butt.face_color = ILI9341_CASET;
  butt.txt_color = ILI9341_DARKGREY;
  butt.border_color = ILI9341_MAGENTA;
  butt.roundRect = false;
  butt.createButton("Press!");
```

and in `void loop()`:

```
  if (ts.touched())
  {
    TS_Point p = ts.getPoint();
    if (butt.checkPress(p))
      {
        Serial.print("Pressed");
      }
  }
```

**3) `buttonArrayTFT`**

Evolving to `buttonArrayTFT`, which spreads up to 8 buttons x and y centered on screen. Here again using same way to reference relevant properties (in `buttonArrayTFT` each button's size and position are not defined by user, but calculated to optimize size and position). Now variable are referenced to a `ButtonTFT` instance, for example `&txt_size = _button0.txt_size` as shown below.

Since `txt_size` is common for all button members in that array of buttons, it is referenced for all buttons later in code.

Also `buttonArrayTFT` works as expected, when defining its instance as:

```
char *a[] = {"All Windows", "Saloon", "Room", "Specific"};
buttonArrayTFT mainWindows;
```

and created:

```
  mainWindows.create_array(4, 1, a);
```

as a 4X1 button array with text for each button as in `a`.

**The Problem (code crashes)**

when trying to pass a value for any of referenced parameter ( taking `txt_size` as an example ):

```
mainWindows.txt_size = 3;          // <----- This 
mainWindows.create_array(4, 1, a);
```

While when doing same thing when initiating a button (see up ), I use same way to update button's text size (which is refenced to `MessageTFT` ).

What may be the reason for that ??

Guy

`.h` file:

```
#ifndef TFT_GUI_h
#define TFT_GUI_h

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_ILI9341.h>
#include <XPT2046_Touchscreen.h>

/* Screen calibration */
#define TS_MIN_X 350
#define TS_MIN_Y 350
#define TS_MAX_X 3800
#define TS_MAX_Y 3800
/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

/* For Wemos Mini and TFT screen 2.4" */
#define TFT_CS D0
#define TFT_DC D8
#define TFT_RST -1
#define TS_CS D3
/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

const uint8_t _pos_corr_factor_x = 3;
const uint8_t _pos_corr_factor_y = 4;

extern XPT2046_Touchscreen ts; /* Touch screen */
extern Adafruit_ILI9341 tft;   /* Graphics */

class MessageTFT
{
public:
  int xc = 0;
  int yc = 0;
  uint8_t a = 0;
  uint8_t b = 0;
  uint8_t txt_size = 3;
  uint8_t border_thickness = 1;
  char txt_buf[20];
  bool roundRect = true;
  uint8_t screen_rotation = 0;
  uint16_t face_color = ILI9341_GREENYELLOW;
  uint16_t txt_color = ILI9341_BLACK;
  uint16_t border_color = ILI9341_RED;
  Adafruit_ILI9341 *TFT[1];

public:
  MessageTFT(Adafruit_ILI9341 &_tft = tft);
  void createMSG(char *txt);
  void clear_screen(uint8_t c = 0);

private:
  void _put_text(char *txt);
  void _drawFace();
  void _drawBorder();
};

class ButtonTFT
{
public:
  /* Following vars belong to MSG class*/
  MessageTFT MSGwindow;
  int &xc = MSGwindow.xc;
  int &yc = MSGwindow.yc;
  uint8_t &a = MSGwindow.a;
  uint8_t &b = MSGwindow.b;
  uint8_t &txt_size = MSGwindow.txt_size;
  uint8_t &screen_rotation = MSGwindow.screen_rotation;
  uint16_t &face_color = MSGwindow.face_color;
  uint16_t &txt_color = MSGwindow.txt_color;
  uint16_t &border_color = MSGwindow.border_color;
  bool &roundRect = MSGwindow.roundRect;
  char *txt_buf = MSGwindow.txt_buf;
  /* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

  XPT2046_Touchscreen *TS[1];

public:
  ButtonTFT(XPT2046_Touchscreen &_ts = ts, Adafruit_ILI9341 &_tft = tft);
  void createButton(char *txt);
  bool wait4press();
  bool checkPress(TS_Point &p);

private:
  int _tft_x, _tft_y;

private:
  void _put_text();
  void _press_cb();
  /* fucntions below converts touchscreen values to TFT coordinates */
  void _conv_ts_tft(TS_Point &p);
  bool _check_press_geometry(TS_Point &p);
  int _TS2TFT_x(int px);
  int _TS2TFT_y(int py);
};


class buttonArrayTFT
{
public:
  buttonArrayTFT(XPT2046_Touchscreen &_ts = ts, Adafruit_ILI9341 &_tft = tft);
  void create_array(uint8_t R, uint8_t C, char *but_txt[]);
  uint8_t checkPress(TS_Point &p);

public:
  uint8_t &txt_size = _button0.txt_size;
  uint16_t &txt_color = _button0.txt_color;
  uint16_t &border_color = _button0.border_color;
  bool &roundRect = _button0.roundRect;
  int shift_array = 0;

private:
  ButtonTFT _button0;
  ButtonTFT _button1;
  ButtonTFT _button2;
  ButtonTFT _button3;
  ButtonTFT _button4;
  ButtonTFT _button5;
  ButtonTFT _button6;
  ButtonTFT _button7;
  ButtonTFT *_buttons[8] = {&_button0, &_button1, &_button2, &_button3,
                            &_button4, &_button5, &_button6, &_button7};

private:
  uint8_t _num_items = 0;
};


#endif
```

**Edit1: How Constructors are defined in `.cpp` file**

```
MessageTFT::MessageTFT(Adafruit_ILI9341 &_tft)
{
  TFT[0] = &_tft; // <--- stored in a pointer
}
```

and

```
ButtonTFT::ButtonTFT(XPT2046_Touchscreen &_ts, Adafruit_ILI9341 &_tft) : MSGwindow(_tft)
{
  MSGwindow.TFT[0] = &_tft;
  TS[0] = &_ts;
}
```

and

```
buttonArrayTFT::buttonArrayTFT(XPT2046_Touchscreen &_ts, Adafruit_ILI9341 &_tft)
    : _button0(_ts, _tft), _button1(_ts, _tft), _button2(_ts, _tft),
      _button3(_ts, _tft), _button4(_ts, _tft), _button5(_ts, _tft),
      _button6(_ts, _tft), _button7(_ts, _tft)
{
  _button0.MSGwindow.TFT[0] = &_tft;
  _button0.TS[0] = &_ts;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you should actually be using inheritance and polymorphism for this task.

Comment: For example in my display library [twButton](https://github.com/CariadDisplayLibrary/Widgets/blob/master/src/twButton.h) inherits from [Widget](https://github.com/CariadDisplayLibrary/Cariad/blob/master/src/Cariad.h#L541) which itself is a form of [Image](https://github.com/CariadDisplayLibrary/Cariad/blob/master/src/Cariad.h#L476) that is then a virtual [Cariad](https://github.com/CariadDisplayLibrary/Cariad/blob/master/src/Cariad.h#L135) display device.

Comment: @Majenko can you please tell what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what value this is going to have for Arduino users, but here goes. Your question seem to be an over-complicated form of this the following:

*My code:*

```cpp
struct MessageTFT {uint8_t txt_size = 3;};

struct ButtonTFT {
  MessageTFT MSGwindow;
  uint8_t &txt_size = MSGwindow.txt_size;
};

struct buttonArrayTFT {
  uint8_t &txt_size = _button0.txt_size;
  ButtonTFT _button0;
};

buttonArrayTFT bat;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(F("\n\n\nStart."));
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(bat.txt_size++, DEC);
  delay(1000);
}
```

My question:

*Why does this crash? ...or not print the correct value? or whatever.*

I don't *think* I'm straw-manning (for lack of better term) your question.  But, the question is kind of a mess, so this a best-effort response to it.
If I've clarified the question to the point of being off-topic, so be it. If I do have the correct distillation, if nothing else what people can get out of this is that your questions here can usually be made simpler.

The declared order of members in a class is relevant to the order of initialization; there's more to it than just that. In any case, `_button0` has not been initialized prior to your `uint8_t &txt_size = _button0.txt_size;` The mechanism underlying a member reference in a class is basically that of a pointer.  You are essentially copying an uninitialized pointer out of `_button0` and into the `txt_size` member of `buttonArrayTFT`; that is the `uint8_t &txt_size = MSGwindow.txt_size` has not yet been executed.

You can fix this by doing nothing more than reordering the members like so:

```cpp
struct buttonArrayTFT {
  ButtonTFT _button0;
  uint8_t &txt_size = _button0.txt_size;
};
```

Now `uint8_t &txt_size = MSGwindow.txt_size;` in `ButtonTFT` executes prior to `uint8_t &txt_size = _button0.txt_size;` in `buttonArrayTFT`.

This will fix the problem as I've presented. Should you do this? I'm not sure. But then that's not what was asked anyway. Still, you may be better served by getting rid reference members or converting them to inline functions that return a reference type. Or any number of other strategies.

At a minimum this is a problem your code has.

Comment: Re “_You are essentially copying an uninitialized pointer_”: My understanding is that, even though `_button0` has not been _initialized_ at this point, it has already been _allocated_. He is thus copying a pointer to uninitialized data, not an uninitialized pointer. Did I miss something?

Comment: The mechanism underlying  `uint8_t &txt_size` in `ButtonTFT` is roughly speaking a pointer. When the reference in `ButtonTFT` is *bound* to  the `txt_size` field in `MSGwindow`, it is initing two bytes of `ButtonTFT` with the address of the field in `MSGwindow`. Those two bytes (which are basically a pointer) have not be initialized prior to `uint8_t &txt_size = _button0.txt_size;` The `uint8_t &txt_size = _button0.txt_size;`  is binding the `txt_size` reference of `buttonArrayTFT` to its counterpart in the `ButtonTFT` member.This binding is effectively the copying of an (unitialized) pointer.

Comment: I'm not sure I do it justice in a comment, I mangled the above pretty bad trying to make it fit. If you want you can find me on libera.chat and I'll explain there.  Or spend some time with it and if it's still not making sense, I will try to update the answer later. The "pointers" I'm speaking of are only to illustrate what's happening underneath the references in terms of something that may already be understood.

Comment: Now it is clearer in my mind, thanks!

Comment: @timemage I don't understand why did you assume `_button0` is not initiaed correctly. please see EDIT 1 in my question

Comment: In `buttonArrayTFT` you have `uint8_t &txt_size = _button0.txt_size;` and seven lines later you have: `ButtonTFT _button0;`  If that is in your code as you've shown it, irrespective of what else is in your code, then what I've said the answer applies.